# How to set variable to specific field when querying

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

I am trying to validate an input box against a field in a database. My question is, how does one check a single input equal to any field in a column? I am able to connect to my query, but am unable to perform the validation. Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'username_auth');

function username_auth() {
        
global $wpdb;

    // INPUT FIELD
$username = $_POST['custom_field_username'];

$user_login_sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT username, FROM registration_info WHERE username");

    if(isset($username) && $username !== $user_login_sql) {
        wc_add_notice(('Incorrect username123'), 'error');
    } 
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always sanitize input fields. Use `$wpdb->get_var` to check a single variable. You forgot to add the compare value to the `WHERE` clause.

```
function username_auth() {
     global $wpdb;

     $username = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_field_username'] );

     $user_login_sql = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT username FROM registration_info WHERE username = '$username' ");

     if( $username !== $user_login_sql ) {
         wc_add_notice(('Incorrect username123'), 'error');
     } 
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly!

Comment: You are welcome.  Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left side next to the answer.  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers